# 2 Column Mysql Date Range Search in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, search, date, range

MySQL column > sdate, edate ( its 2 column).

sdate is start date for project starting and edate is end date for project ending.

so i need to make search between them..

```
<strong>Search</strong><br />
<form method="post" action="search.php">
  Start Report Date : <input type="text" name="sdate" />
  End Report Date : <input type="text" name="edate" />
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Search" />
</form>

This is example data in mysql
sdate             Project Name      edate
22 December 2008  project 1         23 December 2008
25 December 2008  project 2         26 December 2008
24 December 2008  project 3         27 December 2008
1  January 2008   project 4         20 January 2008
10 December 2008  project 5         12 December 2008
```

so let say a user entered sdate ( eg, 22 December 2008 ) and edate ( eg, 30 December 2008 ).

It should display

```
22 December 2008  project 1         23 December 2008
25 December 2008  project 2         26 December 2008
24 December 2008  project 3         27 December 2008
```

So i need a php code sql query which should display entries lies between those 2 dates..

Please help me..

Thanks very much..

Comment: please post the table schema as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming that your `sdate` and `edate` are of MySQL columns type `DATE` you could do the following:

```
SELECT  
  Project_Name
, sdate
, edate
FROM your_table 
WHERE 
  sdate <= '2008-12-26'
 AND 
  edate >= '2008-12-26'
```

or you could use DATEDIFF

```
SELECT  
  Project_Name
, sdate
, edate
FROM your_table 
WHERE 
  DATEDIFF(sdate, '2008-12-26') <= 0
 AND 
  DATEDIFF(edate, '2008-12-26') >= 0
```

The first one is more efficient because MySQL can compare all the rows in your table to a static value. For the second solution it needs to calculate the difference for every row in your table.

If your  `sdate` and `edate` columns are not DATE columns, you are out of luck and need to change them first.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a simple select query with a "where" clause can do the trick.

Peuso-code:

```
select sdate, name, edate 
from your_table 
where sdate >= '22 December 2008' and edate <= '30 December 2008'
```

Comment: MySQL supports only YYYY-MM-DD or YY-MM-DD in date literals.  To use formats like those above, you'd have to parse it using the STR_TO_DATE() function.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, to help with UI, I recommend using phps strtotime() method... it makes for entering dates *very* flexible

Answer (score 0):

First use mktime() on the input from the user

```
$time = mktime(format from user);
```

then do

```
SELECT Project_Name, sdate, edate FROM table WHERE 
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(sdate, '%e %m %Y')) <= '$time'
 AND 
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(edate, '%e %m %Y')) >= '$time'
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT project_name, sdate, edate
  FROM projects
 WHERE sdate <= $_POST['edate']
   AND edate >= $_POST['sdate']

Gives you any project with start date and end date that overlap the Form start date and end date.  (assuming the form sdate and edate are in the right format)